# How to trigger rundeck job from public internet where rundeck is behind a VPN?

Tags: networking, webhooks, rundeck

We have rundeck installed on a linux server sitting behind VPN but It has access to internet. Is there any way I can trigger rundeck job outside VPN(like newrelic monitoring which doesn't need P2P VPN).

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the Rundeck host/port in your router exit and reference that external exit in `grails.serverURL` parameter on the `rundeck-config.properties` file (and restart Rundeck service). Anyway, expose Rundeck to the Internet it's too risky and definitely isn't recommended.